# MS Access Run-time error 3044 following Database files transfer

Tags: vba, ms-access

I copied a Microsoft access database to my computer so as to replicate and study customer workflow. When I open application and login I get an error message `"'\\192.168.10.2\Shared\Databases\XXX - Data.mdb' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides."`
But before I login, the moment I fire up the application there is a warning message saying `"This database contains links to external tables..."` and pressing the ok button sends me to the login screen where the actual error pops following login.

VBA is not my thing, for hours I have been searching within the VBA code for any hardcoded path without success.

Can anyone assist to point out where to begin with to narrow down the problem?

Note: 192.168.10.2 is the actual IP of the server which I copied the file from.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like the app is running some code and/or accessing other databases. Try opening it while holding the Shift-key down (keep it pressed until MsAccess opens. Is the file you are opening .mdb, .accdb, .accde, or something else?

Comment: Hello @tinazmu thank you for your response. When hold shift i saw all the tables and was able to find the Link Table Manager which in turn I saw the problematic IP address of previous location. And yes the data file is .mdb currently opened in Office 2019.

Comment: So, can we say that the problem is solved?

Comment: For the table part, I can say the problem is solved. However, I still get connection error related to old server IP but this time a bit different without the error 3044. I suspect the new culprit might be the database queries objects.